# How would you explain this type of syntax (casting)?

Tags: go

Looking at the source code `c.Organizations = (*OrganizationsService)(&c.common)` from https://github.com/google/go-github/blob/master/github/github.go#L283, in describing this bit of code with proper terminology, would you describe it as follows:

*The Organizations field of variable c is set to the address of c.common casted to a pointer receiver value of OrganizationsService.*

Or am I missing a bit of nuance when describing this?

Below are some relevant bits of source code that show where the variables are being defined.

```
// A Client manages communication with the GitHub API.
type Client struct {
    clientMu sync.Mutex   // clientMu protects the client during calls that modify the CheckRedirect func.
    client   *http.Client // HTTP client used to communicate with the API.

    // Base URL for API requests. Defaults to the public GitHub API, but can be
    // set to a domain endpoint to use with GitHub Enterprise. BaseURL should
    // always be specified with a trailing slash.
    BaseURL *url.URL

    // Base URL for uploading files.
    UploadURL *url.URL

    // User agent used when communicating with the GitHub API.
    UserAgent string

    rateMu     sync.Mutex
    rateLimits [categories]Rate // Rate limits for the client as determined by the most recent API calls.

    common service // Reuse a single struct instead of allocating one for each service on the heap.

    // Services used for talking to different parts of the GitHub API.
    Actions        *ActionsService
    Activity       *ActivityService
    Admin          *AdminService
    Apps           *AppsService
    Authorizations *AuthorizationsService
    Checks         *ChecksService
    CodeScanning   *CodeScanningService
    Enterprise     *EnterpriseService
    Gists          *GistsService
    Git            *GitService
    Gitignores     *GitignoresService
    Interactions   *InteractionsService
    IssueImport    *IssueImportService
    Issues         *IssuesService
    Licenses       *LicensesService
    Marketplace    *MarketplaceService
    Migrations     *MigrationService
    Organizations  *OrganizationsService
    Projects       *ProjectsService
    PullRequests   *PullRequestsService
    Reactions      *ReactionsService
    Repositories   *RepositoriesService
    Search         *SearchService
    Teams          *TeamsService
    Users          *UsersService
}

type service struct {
    client *Client
}
```

Comment: The proper terminology is "type conversion".

Comment: The `Organizations` field of `c` is set to the address of  `c.common` converted to a `*OrganizationsService`.  There is no "cast".  There is no receiver in this context.

Answer (score 1):

> The Organizations field of variable c is set to the address of c.common casted to a pointer receiver value of OrganizationsService.

This is close, but I'd make a few changes.

First:

> casted

The operation being done here, according to official Go terminology, is a "conversion" not a cast.

Second:

> c is set to the **address** of c.common...

While `&` is the "addressing" operator, the value that it results in is a *pointer* value.  The literal contents of that value is the address.  It's not incorrect to refer to addresses, but while analyzing syntax and structure, we would probably rather refer to values at the high level, rather than the contents of them.

Third:

> pointer receiver value of...

The word "receiver" in Go refers to the receiver value in method call or method declaration, e.g.

```
func (v *Value) Method()  {
    
}
```

Here `v` is the receiver, and it's type does happen to be a pointer type, but it doesn't have to be.

```
func (v Value) Method()  {
    
}
```

This is also valid (though may have different and unintended effects compared to the first version).  Regardless, the value in your question is not a receiver in any sense.

With the adjustments:

> The Organizations field of variable c is set to the pointer to c.common converted to a pointer value to the OrganizationsService type.

Even still, we could restructure the sentence a bit so it is more similar to the order of operations as they happen in the program.  It may seem natural to analyze things from left to right, but this is rarely the most comprehensible expression of code.

Here's an explanation that is, in my opinion, more natural.

> The pointer to c's "common" field is converted to a pointer to OrganizationsService, and then assigned to c's "Organizations" field.